# Play Framework 2.5 how to add mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework-2.0

I want to add MongoDB in my Play Framework 2.5 Application. 

We can see this module [here](https://www.playframework.com/modules/mongo-1.1/home#aEnabletheMongomodulefortheapplicationa), in the documentation of PF.
How can I add this module in my app? 
The @MongoEntity is really helpfull,but it's writen for 1.* PF app.

There is a MongoDB module for 2.5 PF? 
And an other thing I've tryed: add play-mongo module (by louth) for 2.* but in my build.sbt it's impossible to add them:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkBif.png).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you on Scala or Java?

For Scala, look at [ReactMongo](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo)

For Java, I didnt come across any plugins too, so I started using [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia). Here's how I have configured it

Add this to build.sbt

```
    "org.mongodb.morphia" % "morphia" % "1.2.1",
```

And this to application.conf

```
    mongodb {
      host="localhost"
      port=27017
      database="my_db"
    }
```

Now, you have to create a Singleton class, something like

```
public class MongoConfig {

    private static Datastore datastore;

    public static Datastore datastore() {
        if (datastore == null) {
            initDatastore();
        }
        return datastore;
    }

    public static void initDatastore() {

        final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();

        // Tell Morphia where to find our models
        morphia.mapPackage("models");

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
            ConfigFactory.load().getString("mongodb.host"),
            ConfigFactory.load().getInt("mongodb.port"));

        datastore = morphia.createDatastore(
            mongoClient, ConfigFactory.load().getString("mongodb.database"));
    }

}
```

A sample model

```
@Entity(value = "users", noClassnameStored = true)
public class User {

    public String name;

    public void save() {
        datastore().save(this);
    }

    public User query() {
        return datastore()
            .createQuery(User.class)
            .get();   
    }

}
```

This should work for you. Let me know if I missed anything. Good luck! :)

Comment: I've used jongo and make my custom mongoModel ;) I have forgot to edit my **build.sbt** ! xD