# how to deploy playframework with mongodb on kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I want to deploy our project built with nginx, playframework,and mongodb etc. to Kubernetes.

However, i couldn't find any tutorials on internet how to do that. Could anyone advise where i can find the steps to integrate playframework, nginx and mongodb on Kubernetes?

Comment: My project does it. Is it still relevant for you? If yes, I will describe here. Generally, I have nginx which is reversed proxy to Java play, which fetches data from mongo.

Comment: @YuriR can you describe more? many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my project i use [DockerPlugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) to create docker images and to push them to AWS registry (ECR). So every time i want to update a backend image i run sbt and it pushes a new version to docker repository.

To work with mongo i use [morphia](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/releases), it's not reactive, but easy to use. If performance is very important for you i would recommend you to use async driver, but the code will be less easy to read. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377276/play-framework-2-5-how-to-add-mongodb) you can see example of how to add morphia to play!.

Once you have your play project built and stored as docker image you can deploy it to kubernetes, for that you will need provide a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). In service you should open just default port 9000 to your play deployment.

Next step is to deploy nginx, just use standard image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/). Actually, you can use [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) instead, it will wrap nginx version which is more kuberenetess friendly.
Once you have nginx you need to add there a route, from port 80 or 443 to your play server to port 9000.

This is very high level description, hope it helps. I don't post here build.sbt, deployment, services and nginx configuration files since they are very long.